# configure the EHCache in Mule

Tags: spring, caching, mule, ehcache

Below is the configuration for custom object store ehcache in mule.

My problem is when i start debugging this flow, I'm receiving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager exception.

I've imported the ehcache jar properly, But still receiving this error.

Comment: Your configuration is not visible .. make sure you have written it under code tag

Answer (score 2):

This is a very **common** **problem** in Mule .

If you have issues with EHCache classloading in Mule, place the EHCache jars inside $MULE_HOME/lib/user rather than in your application

For AnypointStudio, you can follow this same procedure, but instead of copying the EHCache jars to $MULE_HOME/lib/user, copy them to $MULE_STUDIO_INSTALL_DIR/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.$version/mule/lib/user

See in the comment section here :- http://ricston.com/blog/cache-scope-ehcache/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put some overrides to the `mule-deploy.properties` file. In our file, we have this override to make spring cache work:

```
loader.override=org.springframework.cache
```

With this configuration there's no need to add ehcache jars to mule's lib folder.